# How to get acess to event in keyup through keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question seems weird but let me tell you the story:

As you might know `e.keycode` gained from `keyup` differs from `e.keyCode` in `keypress` specially when its about bilingual cases.

For instance when the keyboard language is Persian and I press `A`, e.keyCode on key press returns `1588` while e.keyCode on keyup returns `65`.

I need to get access to e.keycode offered by keyup when I'm handling keypress, I used data(), but there is a delay to value be set, something like following:

```
$("#textBox").on("keyup", function(e){
   var keycode = e.keyCode;
   $(this).data('code-on-keyup', keycode);
}) 

$("#textBox").on("keypress", function(e){
   var keycodeOnKeypress = e.keyCode,
       keycodeOnKeyup = $(this).data('code-on-keyup');
   console.log(keycodeOnKeypress, keycodeOnKeyup);
});
```

I get `undefined` for keycodeOnKeyup at the first time and the next time I get keycode generated from one step before.

You might suggest to use `setTimeout()` for keypress but it doesn't sound good, can't I send it as a parameter?

would you suggest me a method to get access to it?

**Update**:
Thanks to @Amadan, that was easier that what I thought, I should have used `keydown` instead of `keyup`:

```
$("#textBox").on("keydown", function(e){
   var keycode = e.keyCode;
   $(this).data('code-on-keydown', keycode);
}) 

$("#textBox").on("keypress", function(e){
   var keycodeOnKeypress = e.keyCode,
       keycodeOnKeydown = $(this).data('code-on-keydown');
   console.log(keycodeOnKeypress, keycodeOnKeydown);
});
```

Comment: *"I need to get access to e.keycode offered by keyup when I'm handling keypress"*  **why?** Why just don't use and make your logic regarding the value which is coming in the `keypress` event object?

Comment: It doesn't matter why, you know, there is a need. I'm creating a JavaScript file to control entered values, imaging you type for a few seconds and after a while you look at the display screen and you figure out your keyboard language has been in another language, I'm controlling  what user is typing and change it without any need to change keyboard language.

Comment: `keyup` is sent _after_ `keypress`. There can even be multiple `keypress` before `keyup`, You'd need a time travel machine to use `keyup` event data in the corresponding `keypress` handler. Are you sure you can't use `keydown` instead of `keyup`?

Comment: @2oppin is correct, but in fact your code is also working fine. *"I get undefined for keycodeOnKeyup at the first time and the next time I get keycode generated from one step before."* - this happens because `keypress` event is happening before `keyup` event. Basically it is impossible to pass something from `keyup` to `keypress`, because one is happening before another ....

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var theText = $("#theText");
    var theOutputText = ("#theOutputText");
    var theOutputKeyPress = ("#theOutputKeyPress");
    var theOutputKeyDown = ("#theOutputKeyDown");
    var theOutputKeyUp = ("#theOutputKeyUp");
    var theOutputFocusOut = ("#theOutputFocusOut");

    

    theText.keypress(function (event) {
      console.log('keypress');
     keyReport(event, theOutputKeyPress);
      theText.keyup(function (event) {
console.log('keyup');
      keyReport(event, theOutputKeyUp);
    });
    });


   

  

 

    function keyReport(event, output) {
        // catch enter key = submit (Safari on iPhone=10)
        if (event.which == 10 || event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        // show event.which
      console.log("Event\t" +event.which + "\tkeyCode\t" + event.keyCode);
        // report invisible keys  
        switch (event.which) {
            case 0:
                output.append("event.which not sure");
                break;
            case 13:
                output.append(" Enter");
                break;
            case 27:
                output.append(" Escape");
                break;
            case 35:
                output.append(" End");
                break;
            case 36:
                output.append(" Home");
                break;
        }
        // show field content
       console.log(theText.val());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="theText">Enter some text</label>
        <input id="theText" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This looks like it will add a new event listener on each keypress event...

Comment: You can run it.

Answer (score 0):

As you might read [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) property is deprecated,
to overcome this you can use "key" property:

```
eventObject.key.charCodeAt(0)
```

So your code might be like

```
$("#textBox").on("keyup", function(e){
   var keycode = e.originalEvent.key.charCodeAt(0);
   $(this).data('code-on-keyup', keycode);
})

$("#textBox").on("keypress", function(e){
   var keycodeOnKeypress = e.originalEvent.key.charCodeAt(0),
       keycodeOnKeyup = $(this).data('code-on-keyup');
   console.log(keycodeOnKeypress, keycodeOnKeyup);
});
```